# vsftpd and filezilla

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, filezilla

I've installed vsftpd and filezilla locally on my pc(ubuntu 12.04)

I can enter ftp via filezilla using 0.0.0.0 and it works.
How can i access to ftp from outside of my computer?
What address should i use?

vsftpd.config

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Comment: use `ip a s`  to show your adresses, any adress not in 127.0.0.1 will do. You may have to use proper certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still bind it to 0.0.0.0, however you have to open the port with your firewall interface (depends, probably ufw or iptables on ubuntu). 0.0.0.0 binds to all interfaces (localhost as well as for example your ethernet interface).
I recommend to search in the ubuntu documentation about firewalls.
If your computer is behind a commonly configured home router and you want to make it available on the internet, you also have to set up a port forward on your router to your pc, this procedure varies from router to router.
You also have to be aware of the security or legal issues of running a public ftp server, especially if you use `anonymous_enable=YES`.